# Construir JSONArray desde base de datos SQLite

Tags: java, android, json

Tengo un método con el que quiero poner unos registros de la BD en un `JSON` array, para ello antes creo un `JSON Object` para que cada nombre de campo lleve su valor, el detalle que tengo 50 registros y me crea un JSON array con 50 `JSON object` pero lo que esta haciendo es que el ultimo registro lo esta ingresando 50 veces.

El siguiente es el código

```
public JSONArray getInsertPesquisas() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject joPesquisas = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray joTotal = new JSONArray();
    List<PlPesquisaLarvaria> pesquisas;
    PlPesquisaLarvariaDao pesDao = daoSession.getPlPesquisaLarvariaDao();
    pesquisas = pesDao.queryBuilder().where(PlPesquisaLarvariaDao.Properties.Estado_sync.eq(1)).list();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    for (PlPesquisaLarvaria p : pesquisas) {
        String date = dateFormat.format(p.getFecha());
        joPesquisas.put("id", p.getId());
        joPesquisas.put("idTablet", p.getIdTablet());
        joPesquisas.put("idSibasi", p.getIdSibasi());
        joPesquisas.put("idSemana", p.getIdSemanaEpidemiologica());
        joPesquisas.put("idCriadero", p.getIdCriadero());
        joPesquisas.put("idCaserio", p.getIdCaserio());
        joPesquisas.put("idUsuario", p.getIdUsuarioReg());
        joPesquisas.put("idEstado", p.getIdEstado());
        joPesquisas.put("fecha", p.getFechaHoraReg());
        joPesquisas.put("indice", p.getIndiceLarvario());
        joPesquisas.put("anopheles34", p.getAnophelesDos());
        joPesquisas.put("anopheles12", p.getAnophelesUno());
        joPesquisas.put("culicino12", p.getCulicinosUno());
        joPesquisas.put("culicino34", p.getCulicinosDos());
        joPesquisas.put("pupa", p.getPupa());
        joPesquisas.put("cucharonadas", p.getNumeroCucharonada());
        joPesquisas.put("ancho", p.getAncho());
        joPesquisas.put("largo", p.getLargo());
        joTotal.put(joPesquisas);
    }
    return joTotal;
}
```

Así construí el `JSON` el formato del `JSON` seria así el deseado:

```
[
{
    "id":50,
    "idTablet":2,
    "idSibasi":14,
    "idSemana":39,
    "idCriadero":338,
    "idCaserio":4987,
    "idUsuario":11,
    "idEstado":1,
    "fecha":"2018-09-27"
},
{
    "id":51,
    "idTablet":2,
    "idSibasi":14,
    "idSemana":39,
    "idCriadero":338,
    "idCaserio":4987,
    "idUsuario":11,
    "idEstado":1,
    "fecha":"2018-09-27"
},
{
    "id":52,
    "idTablet":2,
    "idSibasi":14,
    "idSemana":39,
    "idCriadero":338,
    "idCaserio":4987,
    "idUsuario":11,
    "idEstado":1,
    "fecha":"2018-09-27"
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tiene que volver a crear tu objeto en cada ciclo

```
for (PlPesquisaLarvaria p : pesquisas) {
    joPesquisas = new JSONObject(); // se tiene que crear de nuevo tu objeto
    String date = dateFormat.format(p.getFecha());

      ...(demas codigo)

    joTotal.put(joPesquisas);
}
return joTotal;
```

}